# How to make a QGraphicsTextItem clickable?

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, qgraphicstextitem

In the "About box" of my software, I used a `QGraphicsTextItem` to show the about-text.

This text contains hypertext links (in the form  of: `<a href="http://some.random.site">link</a>`).

The item shows up properly (hypertext links are blue and underlined). However, when I click on them, nothing happens.

Here is how I created the `QGraphicsTextItem`:

```
d_about_text_item = new QGraphicsTextItem;
d_about_text_item->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
d_about_text_item->setHtml(aboutText());
```

As I understand the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt.html#TextInteractionFlag-enum), the call to `setTextInteractionFlags` should allow me to handle special hypertext links click events.

Is there anything else I should do to be able to click on the links and show up the linked page in the default system browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I did wrong:

My containing `QGraphicsView` had `setInteractive()` set to `false`. I removed it and since now, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I use the standard QMessageBox::about method and simply pass raw HTML as the text - links work fine.

```
QMessageBox::about(this, tr("About"), tr("<h1>My App</h1><p><a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>Click me!</a></p>"));
```